# Temporary failure in name resolution after upgrade to Debian Buster

Tags: debian, upgrade, host-name-resolution

I upgraded a few machines to Debian Buster and everything went well so far—although when running `apt upgrade` before `apt full-upgrade` I ran into a
 `Temporary failure in name resolution`. This was fixable and only an issue during the process and did not occur when doing a one-step `apt dist-upgrade`. However one machine shows this behaviour in spite of being fully upgraded. I get

```
~# LANG=C ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

When I add google.com to `/etc/hosts` everything is fine. My `/etc/nsswitch` looks like

```
~# cat /etc/nsswitch.conf 

passwd:         files systemd
group:          files systemd
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

My `/etc/resolv.conf` points to googles nameserver at the moment and the very server is pingable

```
~# cat /etc/resolv.conf 

nameserver 8.8.8.8

~# ping -c1 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=22.8 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 22.800/22.800/22.800/0.000 ms
```

`systemd-resolved` is inactive and should not be an issue if I am interpreting the content of my `/etc/nsswitch` correctly.

Could there be another point I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing `nslookup` pointed me to the source of the problem: `resolv.conf` was simply not parseable. I copied the contents from the original file into a new one and everything works. Same content, same permissions. But `diff` shows a difference where is none. Apparently there is some invisible character breaking the file since it is 1 Byte larger

```
/etc# diff resolv.conf.odd resolv.conf.dem
1c1
< nameserver 8.8.8.8
---
> nameserver 8.8.8.8
/etc# cat resolv.conf.odd && cat resolv.conf.dem
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.8.8
/etc# ls -l resolv.conf.*|cut -d' ' -f5,9
19 resolv.conf.dem
20 resolv.conf.odd
```

Update: As cas thankfully pointed out it was a trailing `\r` causing the mayhem and had nothing to do with the Buster Update itself. A coworker had pushed the file with wrong line wrappings

```
$ hd resolv.conf.odd
00000000  6e 61 6d 65 73 65 72 76  65 72 20 38 2e 38 2e 38  |nameserver 8.8.8|
00000010  2e 38 0d 0a                                       |.8..|
```

Comment: if you're still curious now that you've fixed it, you can find out what the problematic byte is with `cat -V` or a hexdumper like `hd` or `xxd`.   My guess is it's probably a carriage-return character (0x0d or \r).

Comment: thank you, cas—It was indeed the carriage return.

Comment: thank you, just if someone is looking for a quick fix: `a=$(printf "nameserver 8.8.8.8\r");
echo $a >/etc/resolv.conf `

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/o82856/need_help_with_dns_systemdresolved_when_using_dhcp/) to a version of this problem that has (almost?) identical symptoms.

In short:

In my case, I was using systemd-networkd, and name resolution wasn't working. Also, /etc/resolv.conf had different nameservers in than what is returned by our DHCP servers (although they were reachable).

Here's what I did:

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved.service
```

Note: I don't know if that systemctl command is "permanent." I suspect something needs to be done to make starting that service on boot. I'm relatively inexperienced with Linux, and the above got me to where I needed to be.