# Temporary failure in name resolution after Debian 10 upgrade

Tags: debian, networking, apt, upgrade, dist-upgrade

I tried to upgrade Debian 8 to 10 by first upgrading it to version 9 and then to 10. I did this by changing /etc/apt/sources.list, running `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`. The upgrade from 8 to 9 went well without issues. Then I changed sources.list to point to the current stable repositories, and upgraded. Like previously, it upgraded with no issues, but after it completed, I found it unable to resolve hostnames for any online resource (`apt update` says `Temporary failure resolving deb.debian.org`, `ping google.com` says `Temporary failure in name resolution`). I tried adding `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to /etc/resolv.conf, but that didn't fix my issue.

I would also like to point out that I am running Debian on an old Asus ME173X Android 4.2.2 (armhf) tablet with chroot in a terminal emulator.

How to fix name resolution?

Comment: What happens when you try `ping 8.8.8.8`? This sounds like a networking problem - has the tablet reconnected to your wifi (or ethernet)?

Comment: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=30.1ms

Comment: OK so not obviously a network problem. Next **guess**, /etc/resolv.conf has CR characters at the end of the lines. Possibly use `mv` to save the current one if you think you might want to look at it later and then use `( echo nameserver 1.1.1.1 ; echo nameserver 9.9.9.9 ; ) > /etc/resolv.conf` to set a different pair of nameservers just in case.

Comment: This question has an answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537035/temporary-failure-in-name-resolution-after-upgrade-to-debian-buster/537039#537039) (icarus is right i guess)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Temporary failure in name resolution after upgrade to Debian Buster](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537035/temporary-failure-in-name-resolution-after-upgrade-to-debian-buster)